# Could not initialize class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-design-library

I am trying to use the CoordinatorLayout from the new Android design library. I added the package to gradle; then I try to use the layout I get this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:413)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:105)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallback.loadView(LayoutlibCallback.java:177)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:207)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:132)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:400)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:332)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:497)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:485)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:894)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:485)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:590)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.doRender(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:644)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.access$1700(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:79)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7$1.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:586)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:152)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:452)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:402)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:137)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:581)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:351)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
```

Anybody have a fix for this? Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. First update android studio to latest version (beta) 1.3 beta version. [Using menu option 'Check for updates' from android studio]
2. Render your preview using Android M preview.

[image]

If you are not able to find the beta update change android studio settings(***Updates***), then update that patch and render with M preview

[image]

Answer (score 17):

This is a known issue. It is open on the Android Open Source Project Issue Tracker:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175595

The workaround described by the Android project member is:

> Workaround: Try rendering with M preview using AS v1.3 preview.

Another way to workaround this issue is to replace your `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout` with a `FrameLayout` when you want to edit it in the visual design editor, make your changes to the layout and then change it back to a `CoordinatorLayout` when you are finished.

Answer (score 11):

may be dependency error. dependencies must be like

```
dependencies {

    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Restarting Android Studio fixed the problem for me, hope this helps...

Comment: i think this is the case when you start android studio for the first time after installation and sdk downloads. Could be related to caching. Restarting the IDE clears the cache and it works afterwards.

Comment: Just had this issue and it wasn't related to installation/updates. A simple restart brought back the preview.

Answer (score 3):

To display a sketch you need to delete a line

```
<tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">
```

from main RelativeLayout

Answer (score 3):

**Edit your code into build.gradle file as below.**

> `compileSdkVersion 24`
>
> `buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"`
>
> `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'`
>
> `compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'`
>
> `testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'`

Answer (score 0):

Try to add these dependencies

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into it using the latest Mac OS X, latest SDK and latest Android Studio. All of them are "stable" versions. Shame on Google testers.

How I fixed it:

1. From menu: **Tools** > **Android** > **SDK manager**
2. In the SDK Manager, check Android 5.0.1 (API 21). Perhaps any other will do.
3. Click "Show package details" at the bottom. Under Android 5.0.1, also check "Google APIs" and "Intel x86 Atom System Image" (why not? if we'll develop for the 21th API)
4. Click OK and wait for the components to download.
5. Like already mentioned in other answers, choose to render the layout with it:

[image: Choose to render layout with the Android API level 21]

Problem solved!