# The following classes could not be instantiated: android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-studio

Anybody know what this is about?

Here are my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.0.0'
}
```

I imported everything from the Android Support Library and synced the Gradles. Anybody know why I am getting rendering problems in the layout?

Here is the error log:

---

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:413)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:105)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallback.loadView(LayoutlibCallback.java:177)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:214)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:142)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:806)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:413)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:321)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:497)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:485)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:894)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:485)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:590)
    at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$6.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:480)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:351)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30927887

Comment: Hmm I tried doing the things that he talked about. Running it on the Android Studio 1.3 Beta doesn't help with rendering it. Changing CoordinatorLayout to FrameLayout in the xml temporarily for editing doesn't matter because if I try to run the app, it will crash due to not being able to find CoordinatorLayout. I'm still trying to work out a better solution.

Comment: @George Before running your app, change your `FrameLayout` back to a `CoordinatorLayout`, so that it can find the `CoordinatorLayout`.

Answer (score 1):

Am also faced same problem as per your scenario after import the support libraries and synced the Gradles need to **rebuild your project**.

After i have done this procedure its working for me, i hope this will helpful.

Comment: I'm not sure rebuilding the project is entirely necessary. Only a Gradle sync.

Comment: after sync also if it is pursuing you can rebuild project or restart the android studio am sure in this case

Comment: please refer this link also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30879510/could-not-initialize-class-android-support-design-widget-coordinatorlayout

Comment: this is the simple solution to solve this without issue tracker

Answer (score 0):

> The following classes could not be instantiated: android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout

This is simply because `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout` is [added in version 24.1.0](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout). So, the support library dependency is incorrect. The dependencies should be updated at least to version `24.1.0` or using the latest support libraries (28.0.0). Something like this:

```
dependencies {

    compile 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:28.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:28.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
}
```