# Issue with Android Studio 3.0.1

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

Hey people,

I'm having this problem about a few hours. I already tried with Invalider cache/Restart but didn't work also I downloaded the last versions of the SDK Tools. Anyone knows how to solve it?

This is my gradle

[image]

Also, I'm having this issue too

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: change your compileSdkVersion to 26 it will work for me

Comment: Show your gradle file, please.

Comment: On the preview layout try changing the API version 26 to a different API version

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not initialize class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30879510/could-not-initialize-class-android-support-design-widget-coordinatorlayout)

Comment: Changing the compile / render version won't make classes magically be found.... Compiling that dependency will

Comment: Also, if you downloaded the latest version, that's 27, but looks like you're still using 26

Comment: @cricket_007 I added my gradle file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `app` level `build.gradle` file, specify:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.3'
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add **constraint-layout** dependency also.

```
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta3'
```

and try adding **AppCompact** support in dependency.

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0'
```

** Please change version names according to your build.

Answer (score 0):

The render in Layout is 26 while in the gradle the targetSdkVersion is 25